# trouble baking displacment map

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, normal-map, displacement, height-map

in trying to bake a high poly sculpt displacment map onto a low poly base mesh, and not having much success, there seems to be not alot of info out there on this particular subject (from what ive seen and read blender perhaps isn't the best program for this process),

[image: hi poly sculpt and low poly base mesh]

am i right in thinking that the low poly mesh has to completly cover the high poly? I saw this mentioned only in passing in a tutorial and not realy explained, other tutorials i have seen are only showing a plane being displaced

or is or is a degree of intersecttion (over and under lapping meshes where sculpted details from the base mesh excede the bounds of low poly) ok or even prefered (this dosnt seem to be a problem when baking normal maps)
[image]
[image: hi poly intersecting with original base mesh]

I've only realy had any degree of success with the high poly being within the bounds of the low poly, but the resulting displacement image is lacks contrast, and dosen't affect the mesh simply imposing an image on the low
i tried adding a contrast node to ramp up the potential effects of the 'weak' displacement map image to no effect
[image: only results acheaved]
[image]
[image]
[image]

please could somone walk me through what the correct aproach might be in this case and what i should consider ive only seen demos using simple planes, 
for example 
--- is my base mesh too low in polycount?
--- are the sculpted details too far from base mesh?
--- could there be sothing overlooked that might be a problem (smooth shading ect)

hope i've made my problem clear, 
i will try to upload a blend file with a decimated high poly sculpt

cheers,
billy

Comment: What Blender version are you on? If you are in 2.79 you need to switch to "experimental feature set" and in the Material under the section "settings" set Displacement from Bump to "True" or "Booth" then the actual Mesh will be displaced. I can walk you trough the creation also, altough its probably best if i do it with your model.

Comment: hello, yes im on 2.79, and thank you for getting back to me so quickly i will look into the experimental features, i tryed to upload the blend file through the blend exchange (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/),---- is there any prefered method for you to reaceve the file for you to have a look? cheers, billy

Comment: here is the download link to the file let me know if it works!, cheers        [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5915" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5915/)

Comment: i'll get to it as soon as i can. Thanks for uploading in the meantime.

Comment: That’s very kind of you cheers

Comment: I'm busy atm so i can't get around writing a comprehension sadly, but there just arrived this short video, which explains the key parts :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHxv1aNsIPg if there are questions i can answer them.

Comment: hey thank you for letting me kniow ill give it a watch

Comment: im getting some good results from the video cheers

Comment: Thats great! :)